# Where can it be differentiated and what's the derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1}{n!}$ when $x \in [2^{-n-1},2^{-n})$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise?

Tags: derivatives

I need to find where the following function is differentiable and what the derivative there:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{n!} & \text{if} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\leqslant x< \frac{1}{2^n} \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N} \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}$$
It's easy to see that
$$f'(x)=0 \;\forall x \in(-\infty,0) \cup(1, \infty) \cup \left(\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, \frac{1}{2^n}\right)\right)$$
and it's not continuous at $x=\frac{1}{2^n}$, so it can't be differentiated there. Now I am only left with $x=0$. If the limit exists it must be $0$ because: $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{f(h)}{h}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n!}}{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}}{n!}=0$$
But how could I prove that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$ exists?

Comment: I don’t understand if $n$ is fixed or not. If n is fixed then f_n(x) is a locally constant function

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Sorry, it is not fixed.

Comment: There is not x that satisfies your condition for each n

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Could you give an example? For example, if $x=0.75$, then $n=0$.

Comment: Sure but if x=0.75 must satisfies your condition for every n then for n=1 you have that 0.75<0.5 that it is not true

Comment: @FedericoFallucca The $n$ is just used in the definition of the function, which is piecewise constant. The $n$ is just used to describe that interval where it is constant.

Comment: So it is wrong the language of his question?

Comment: Ooooops, sorry..I read for ANY n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $\epsilon > 0$, then as you wrote

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n!}}{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}}{n!}=0,$$

so there is an $N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{\frac{1}{n!}}{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}} < \epsilon,$ if $n \ge N(\epsilon)$.

For $\lvert h\rvert < \frac1{2^{N(\epsilon)}}$ we have

$$f(h)=0,\text{ if } h < 0.$$

If $h > 0$, we have $\frac1{2^{m+1}} \le h <  \frac1{2^{m}}$ for some $m \ge N(\epsilon)$, so we have

$$0 < \frac{f(h)}h = \frac{\frac1{m!}}h \le \frac{\frac1{m!}}{\frac1{2^{m+1}}} < \epsilon,$$

because $m \ge N(\epsilon)$.

So in both cases ($h < 0, h > 0$) we get

$$\left\lvert \frac{f(h)}h - 0\right\rvert < \epsilon$$

if $h$ is sufficiently near $0$, so $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}h$ exists and is $0$.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now!

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that the limits from the left and the right are equal to $0$. It follows that the limit exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: I know. I did calculate it from the left and along $1$ sequence from the right, but I can't prove that it's true for every sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: It's a step function, so it is just that one sequence from the right. No matter what (decreasing) $(a_n)$ you take, $f(a_n)$ is a subsequence (maybe with repeated elements) of the one you showed limits to $0$.

Comment: Thank you, I see now!